# Unable to copy data from one table to another where id=1

Tags: sql, t-sql

Hey guys i am quite a newbie here, what i am trying to do is i am trying to
copy data (skills) column from one temp table to another table where id=1;

now **Table one called skillmapping has candidateId and skillName columns**

**Table2 has only skillName column**

**I am trying to insert data from Table 2 to Table 1 where the canidateId=1**

Please help me with this. i tried copy data but seems like error for candidateId..
thanks.

I tried this but says incorrect syntax

```
 insert into candidateComputerSkillMapping(skillname) values(select * from tempComputerSkillMap)
```

**Thanks for All the answers guys, i guess columns on both tables should be same i mean both should have an id and skillName then only we can copy right.. thanks anyways,**

Comment: `insert into Table2 select skillname from Table1 where candidateid = 1`

Comment: your insert query is wrong instead of `select * from tempComputerSkillMap` try to use `select skillname from tempComputerSkillMap` because you want ot insert only skillname value into table `candidateComputerSkillMapping`..hope you understand, `*` means `all columns`..

Comment: `insert into candidateComputerSkillMapping select skillName from tempComputerSkillMap where candidateid = 1` should work. Please post your create table script

Comment: that's does not matter that `both tables should be same i mean both should have an id and skillName then only we can copy right`..actually if your `id` is primary key then it will create problem beacuse you cannot assign `null` value to primary key while `inserting` otherwise that's doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

Try to make a query like

```
INSERT INTO candidateComputerSkillMapping (skillName)
SELECT skillName
FROM tempComputerSkillMap
WHERE candidateId=1;
```

Or

```
INSERT INTO candidateComputerSkillMapping
SELECT skillName
FROM tempComputerSkillMap
WHERE candidateId=1;
```

Check [sqlauthority](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/08/15/sql-server-insert-data-from-one-table-to-another-table-insert-into-select-select-into-table/)

If `candidateId` in `candidateComputerSkillMapping` table is `primaryid` then you cannot insert `null` to primary key and it will give error.That's why show These two tables structure for good answer.

Hope it works.

Comment: dear you want to insert `table 2` data to `table 1` or `table 1` data to `table 2`..

Comment: i am trying to insert data from table2 to table1 and the problem is that table2 only contains skillname and i want to add that data to table 1 where we have a skillId=1

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO [Table2] SELECT skillName FROM [skillmapping] WHERE candidateId = 1
```

Comment: It says an Error Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition. I guess because i don't have candidateId on skillmapping table.. is there any other way. thanks

Comment: As you said you have candidateId on your skillmapping table. Did I understand wrong?

Answer (score 0):

if you think data already exist and you need to update it then...

```
update Table2 set skillname = (select skillname from Table1 where candidateid =1)
```

if you think you need to insert new record then....

```
insert into Table2 select skillname from Table1 where candidateid = 1
```

Comment: Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.  this is theerror.

Comment: try... insert into Table2 (skillname) values (select skillname from Table1 where candidateid= 1)

Comment: @PavanKumarK your query should work `insert into Table2 select skillname from Table1 where candidateid = 1`

Comment: Yes Wrong query by Pavan, actually, i tried this too  but it says incorrect syntax  insert into candidateComputerSkillMapping(skillname) values
   (select * from tempComputerSkillMap)

Comment: @designerNProgrammer can you post the table script?

Answer (score 0):

Since your `table2` doesn't have candidateid, I assume at the time of the insert, you are sure that all skills contained in `table2` belong to candidateid = 1.

If the assumption is correct, then you can follow the example below to insert new skills from `table2` into `table1`.

**EDIT: Updated the queries with comments.**

```
use tempdb

-- Pretending this is your table1
create table candidateComputerSkillMapping
(
    candidateid int             not null
    , skillname varchar(128)    not null
    , unique 
    (
        candidateid
        , skillname
    )
)

-- Table1 has one skill for candidateid = 1
insert candidateComputerSkillMapping values (1, 'Old Skill')

-- Prentending this is your table2
create table tempComputerSkillMap
(
    skillname varchar(128) not null
)

-- table2 has two skills. Now since this table doesn't have candidateid, how do I know the skills are for candidateid = 1?
-- I don't know and I am assuming that you are certain that these skills indeed belong to candidateid = 1.
insert tempComputerSkillMap values ('Old skill')
insert tempComputerSkillMap values ('New skill')

-- Insert only new skills from table2 into table1 for candidateid = 1
insert candidateComputerSkillMapping (candidateid, skillname)
select 1, t2.skillname
from tempComputerSkillMap t2
where not exists (select * from candidateComputerSkillMapping t1 where t1.candidateid = 1 and t1.skillname = t2.skillname)

select * from candidateComputerSkillMapping
```

Comment: its confusing, can you tell me in details please. thanks a lot

Comment: If you would like more targeted response, then please update your question with table definition and sample data.